# php code that checks and run process

Tags: php, process, execution, watchdog

there is a process that always terminate abrutply, and is there anyway to monitor it? i dont want to end up manually typing "service named start" or service anyprocess start". i need a php script that checks a process on the server, then if its not running, it will run it. the process "named". also, how can we put a cron to it, like check evry 5 seconds? tnx

the pesudo code goes like this

check process
if process is running
do nothing
else, if is not running
execute "service anyprocess start"

check every 5 seconds.

Comment: Are you saying your `named` crashes? Then your server seems pretty hosed. A *PHP* script is probably *not* the way to fix it. Debug the cause of the problem, a `*d` needs to keep itself running without PHP as a crutch.

Comment: actually its not named. its another process. i just use "named"  any ideas for writing script?

Comment: @Lufthansa: Talk with the system administrator for the system that happens and discuss the issue. He should give you the hints you need to solve the problem. Otherwise do an internet search for watchdog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing would not be some home-grown PHP script, but a tested application that does this for you. There are many, but I am fond of [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/). It does *exactly* what you ask. Watch a daemon or program and if it fails, restart it.

Even better is that your daemon will be restarted immediately and not just whenever you put it in your cron.

Comment: tnx bro! u just saved some coding hours

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this in PHP use [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) instead.

Comment: @Lufthansa that is exactly it. It monitors any process or daemon (amongst other things) and can be set to auto restart it upon failure.